# CSS Transition on hover: animate mouse-out as well

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to animate a css-arrow (pointing to the left) on hover to move slightly right on hover and stay there. Once the mouse hovers out the arrow it should move backwards with the animation as well.

```
@-webkit-keyframes arrow-left {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform:translateX(0);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
        transform:translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-12px);
        transform:translateX(-12px);
    }
}

@keyframes arrow-left {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
        transform:translateX(0);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
        transform:translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-12px);
        transform:translateX(-12px);
    }
}

.arrow-icon.left:hover {
    -webkit-animation:arrow-left 0.35s ease-in;
  animation:arrow-left 0.35s ease-in;
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin:50% 0%;
  transform-origin:50% 0%
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Any idea on how to make the animation out work as well, so it animates back and doesn't jump back?

https://jsfiddle.net/gsvjwxxj/

Comment: It seems to be already, from your fiddle.

Comment: No, only the line is animating backwards, but not the position of the arrow, if you leave with the mouse the translateX(-12px) is jumping backwards without animtion. On hover it animates 12px to the left, on mouse-out it jumps back the 12px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using keyframes to perform the translate, use `transition` plus `cubic-bezier`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.menu-icon').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
 });
  
  /*setTimeout(function () {
        $('.mouse-icon').fadeOut(250, function() { $(this).remove(); });
  }, 5000);*/
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------- /*
 * Animated arrow icon
/* ---------------------------------------------- */
.arrow-icon {
  position: relative;
  width:26px;
  height:4px;
  background:#000;
  cursor: pointer; 
  -webkit-transition: width .15s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier( 0.42, 0.08, 0.18, -0.24);
  -moz-transition: width .15s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier( 0.42, 0.08, 0.18, -0.24);
  -o-transition: width .15s ease-in-out, -o-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier( 0.42, 0.08, 0.18, -0.24);
  transition: width .15s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s cubic-bezier( 0.42, 0.08, 0.18, -0.24);
}

.arrow-icon.left:hover, .arrow-icon.right:hover {
  width:36px;
}

.arrow-icon.down:hover, .arrow-icon.up:hover {
  height:36px;
}

.arrow-icon.down:hover:after{
  top: 15px;
}

.arrow-icon:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
}

.arrow-icon.left:before, .arrow-icon.right:before {
  width: 52px;
  height: 26px;
}

.arrow-icon.down:before, .arrow-icon.up:before {
  width: 26px;
  height: 52px;
}

.arrow-icon:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width: 52px;
  height: 26px;
}

.arrow-icon.left:before {
  top: -12px;
  left: -12px;
}

.arrow-icon.right:before {
  top: -12px;
  left: -12px;
}

.arrow-icon.down:before {
  top: -12px;
  left: -12px;
}

.arrow-icon.up:before {
  top: -12px;
  left: -12px;
}

.arrow-icon:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  top:-8px;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  background:transparent;
  border-color: #000;
}

.arrow-icon.left:after{
  border-left:4px solid;
  border-bottom:4px solid;
}

.arrow-icon.right:after{
  right:0;
  border-right:4px solid;
  border-top:4px solid;
}

.arrow-icon.down, .arrow-icon.up {
  width: 4px;
  height: 26px;
  left: 10px;
}

.arrow-icon.down:after{
  top: 6px;
  left:-8px;
  border-right:4px solid;
  border-bottom:4px solid;
}

.arrow-icon.up:after {
  top:0px;
  left:-8px;
  border-right:4px solid;
  border-top:4px solid;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

.arrow-icon.left{  
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin:50% 0%;
  transform-origin:50% 0%;
}

.arrow-icon.left:hover {  
  transform:translateX(-12px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow-icon left"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use `animation` for this. you can just use `transform:translateX(-12px)`

see here > **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsvjwxxj/1/)**

or snippet below :

let me know if it helps

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------- /*
 * Animated arrow icon
/* ---------------------------------------------- */
.arrow-icon {
  position: relative;
  width:26px;
  height:4px;
  background:#000;
  cursor: pointer; 
  -webkit-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: .15s ease-in-out;
}

.arrow-icon.left:hover, .arrow-icon.right:hover {
  width:36px;
}



.arrow-icon:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
}

.arrow-icon.left:before, .arrow-icon.right:before {
  width: 52px;
  height: 26px;
}



.arrow-icon:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width: 52px;
  height: 26px;
}

.arrow-icon.left:before {
  top: -12px;
  left: -12px;
}


.arrow-icon:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  top:-8px;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  background:transparent;
  border-color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}

.arrow-icon.left:after{
  border-left:4px solid;
  border-bottom:4px solid;
}









.arrow-icon.left:hover {
   -webkit-transform:translateX(-12px);
  transform:translateX(-12px);
          -ms-transform-origin:50% 0%;
  transform-origin:50% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-icon left"></div>
```